# Recognizing Repetition in strings

Tags: code-golf

Create a program which gets an input from the user and tells the user what repetitions exist in the it. A few examples of inputs the user could give and outputs they should get:

> Input: 112211221122
>
> Output: 1122 * 3

Or:

> Input: 123123
>
> Output: 123 * 2

Or:

> Input: 1234
>
> Output: No repetitions found!

Tiebreaker: if your code can recognize more than one repetition:

> Input: 123123456456
>
> Output: 123 * 2, 456 * 2

Then you win if you are tied for 1st place with someone's code who doesn't recognize more than one repetition.

If your code requires a limit on the repetition length, it should be able to recognize repetitions at least 4 characters long. This is a code-golf question, so the shortest code wins (but please explain the code in your answer)

Comment: Ahem ... I see a clear pattern in your last example.

Comment: You are asking for repetition, not Patterns. Also, please clarify on inputs like `123123456456`. Shuld the output be `123 * 2 456 * 2` or `No repetitions found!`?

Comment: @Quincunx You're absolutely right. I don't know why I was thinking patterns.

Comment: 123123123123 -> 123*4 or 123123*2? Also, 1234 is 1234*1.

Comment: @Doorknob it should break it down into the smallest components (so 123*4). I know 1234 is itself times 1, but that isn't repetition.

Comment: What about nested repetition? `aabbaabb`. Is it `a*2 b*2 a*2 b*2` or `aabb * 2`? Or `a*2 b*2 *2`?

Comment: @KnightOfNi please specify the `extra points`.

Comment: May the answer assume all characters in the strings are digits like in your own examples? I perfectly understand that your question is a string-question, but sometimes assuming such a thing can lead to interesting answers.

Comment: @MukulKumar If your code is tied or close to someone else's but you have the "extra points," the question goes to you.

Comment: @m.buettner The first and third of your examples are valid, but the second is not completely broken down.

Comment: Examples do not make a spec. Please write an actual spec and then move your examples to a section for test cases.

Comment: ass. i had an answer, and now i can't post it.

Comment: I'll post it anyways -> [glot.io](http://glot.io/python/f068ced2a19b17384444b3d6f848dc22)

Comment: @KnightOfNi so the `extra points` don't have any value? (like -30 bytes or -20%)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055035/to-find-all-the-repeating-substring-in-a-given-string

Comment: The tie-break is silly. If code of equal length, then not including the code for the optional task will make it shorter, so no-one will include that code. 1234123412341234 is 1234*4 but 112211221122 is 1122*3 not 1*2 (smallest component). By duplicating characters without explaining how that works for the matching, you get contradictions in the examples.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 74 (73 + 1) bytes

- Assumes `-n` flag (+1 byte).
- `say` is a feature of version 5.10 and needs to be enabled.
  This can be done by flag `-M5.010` or easier with `-E` instead of `-e`.
  Therefore I follow the other Perl [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/24725/16143) in the calculation method of the costs.
- It also reports repetitions as long as they do not overlap.

```perl
s/(.+)(?{$i=1})(\1(?{$i++}))+/say"$1 * $i"/ge||say"No repetitions found!"
```

### Usage and tests

```bash
echo 112211221122 | perl -nE 's/(.+)(?{$i=1})(\1(?{$i++}))+/say"$1 * $i"/ge||say"No repetitions found!"'
1122 * 3
```

```bash
echo 123123 | perl -nE 's/(.+)(?{$i=1})(\1(?{$i++}))+/say"$1 * $i"/ge||say"No repetitions found!"'
123 * 2
```

```bash
echo 1234 | perl -nE 's/(.+)(?{$i=1})(\1(?{$i++}))+/say"$1 * $i"/ge||say"No repetitions found!"'
No repetitions found!
```

```bash
echo 123123456456 | perl -nE 's/(.+)(?{$i=1})(\1(?{$i++}))+/say"$1 * $i"/ge||say"No repetitions found!"'
123 * 2
456 * 2
```

### Ungolfed with comments

```perl
s/
    (.+)              # catches the repeat unit
    (?{ $i=1 })       # initialize counter $1 with 1
    (
        \1            # next repetition
        (?{ $i++ })   # increase counter
    )+                # repeat unit must appear at least twice
/
    say "$1 * $i"     # print result as a side effect of the replacement;
                      # "say" adds a new line at the end
/gex                  # g: global, find all repetitions (without overlap)
                      # e: replacement text is executed as code
                      # x: only ungolfed: readability and comments
    ||                # s/// returns the number of replacements,
                      # this is zero, if no repetitions could be found
    say "No repetitions found!"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl (85 + 1 = 86 bytes)

Assumes `-n` flag (+1 byte) and `-M5.010` (free).

```
length>4&&($i=say"$1 x ",length($&)/length$1)while/(.+)\1+/g}{$i||say"No repetitions found!"
```

Sample:

```
~ $ echo 123123456456 | perl -nE 'length>4&&($i=say"$1 x ",length($&)/length$1)while/(.+)\1+/g}{$i||say"No patterns found!"'
123 x 2
456 x 2
~ $ echo 112211221122 | perl -nE 'length>4&&($i=say"$1 x ",length($&)/length$1)while/(.+)\1+/g}{$i||say"No patterns found!"'
1122 x 3
```

Comment: Since the "No repetitions found!" has to be included in the count as well, you should probably use the extact string from the question; by changing one word, you easely spare 3 characters; while Doorknob's javascript answer uses the exact string from the question.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 81

Assumes input is stored in variable `s`. Run this in a console.

```
x=s.match(/^(.+?)\1+$/)
x?x[1]+" * "+s.length/x[1].length:"No repetitions found!"
```

Does not support multiple repetition, but that is portrayed as optional.

Explanation: regex `/^(.+?)\1+$/` matches one or more characters and then those characters repeated one or more times. `?` is used to make the `+` lazy, so it works for `123123123123`.

Answer (score 0):

## APL 71 characters

```
(1+B<S)⌷(⊂'no repetitions found!'),⊂W[B],S÷B←1⍳⍨∧/¨V=¨S⍴¨W←V↑⍨¨⍳S←⍴⊃V←⊂
```

Example:

```
(1+B<S)⌷(⊂'no repetitions found!'),⊂W[B],S÷B←1⍳⍨∧/¨V=¨S⍴¨W←V↑⍨¨⍳S←⍴⊃V←⊂ '123123'
```

Try it with my online compiled to javascript version of GNU APL: [here](http://baruchel.hd.free.fr/apps/apl/#code=%E2%8E%95%E2%86%90%27Example%201%3A%20%22123123%22%27%0A%281%2BB%3CS%29%E2%8C%B7%28%E2%8A%82%27no%20repetitions%20found!%27%29%2C%E2%8A%82W%5bB%5d%2CS%C3%B7B%E2%86%901%E2%8D%B3%E2%8D%A8%E2%88%A7%2F%C2%A8V%3D%C2%A8S%E2%8D%B4%C2%A8W%E2%86%90V%E2%86%91%E2%8D%A8%C2%A8%E2%8D%B3S%E2%86%90%E2%8D%B4%E2%8A%83V%E2%86%90%E2%8A%82%20%27123123%27%0A%E2%8E%95%E2%86%90%27Example%201%3A%20%22121212%22%27%0A%281%2BB%3CS%29%E2%8C%B7%28%E2%8A%82%27no%20repetitions%20found!%27%29%2C%E2%8A%82W%5bB%5d%2CS%C3%B7B%E2%86%901%E2%8D%B3%E2%8D%A8%E2%88%A7%2F%C2%A8V%3D%C2%A8S%E2%8D%B4%C2%A8W%E2%86%90V%E2%86%91%E2%8D%A8%C2%A8%E2%8D%B3S%E2%86%90%E2%8D%B4%E2%8A%83V%E2%86%90%E2%8A%82%20%27121212%27%0A%E2%8E%95%E2%86%90%27Example%201%3A%20%22123456%22%27%0A%281%2BB%3CS%29%E2%8C%B7%28%E2%8A%82%27no%20repetitions%20found!%27%29%2C%E2%8A%82W%5bB%5d%2CS%C3%B7B%E2%86%901%E2%8D%B3%E2%8D%A8%E2%88%A7%2F%C2%A8V%3D%C2%A8S%E2%8D%B4%C2%A8W%E2%86%90V%E2%86%91%E2%8D%A8%C2%A8%E2%8D%B3S%E2%86%90%E2%8D%B4%E2%8A%83V%E2%86%90%E2%8A%82%20%27123456%27).